# Numpy issubdtype gives "TypeError: data type not understood"

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm running python 2.7 and numpy 1.15.

I get:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.issubdtype(4, float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/brianp/work/cyan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 714, in issubdtype
    arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Did something change so that it used to work with values, but now it only works with types?

As per an answer below:

```
>>> np.issubdtype(4, np.float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/brianp/work/cyan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 714, in issubdtype
    arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
TypeError: data type not understood
```

I should add that

```
>>> np.issubdtype(type(4), np.float)
False
```

works... but the code USED to work without `type()`...

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy types first. Then you want to compare dtypes, not actual values.

```
>>> np.issubdtype(np.float, np.float)
True
```

You cannot compare variables, only types.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't check this with strings? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html There was a change in 1.14, but not on this case.